# msg.sender is Null in Base Constructor

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, inheritance

When I create the child class object and try to access value of msg.sender from parent class it always comes 0. Can anyone please help me in this? Below is the sample code:

```
contract Test1 is Test2 {

    constructor() Test2() {}
}

contract Test2 
{
    address testVal;
    constructor() 
            {testVal= msg.sender;    } 

   function getMSGSender() view returns ( address) {
     return testVal;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little clean-up.

1. You need `Test2` defined before `Test1` inherits from it, so the order is reversed.
2. Add `public` to functions to avoid warning about default visibility.
3. Constructor in `Test1` has nothing *else* to do, so removed. Since it inherits from `Test2`, the `Test2` constructor will run. In case it is not clear, `Test1` will have a state variable called `testVal` and the function `getMSGSender()` and there is no need to deploy `Test2`.

-

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Test2 
{
    address testVal;

    constructor() public {
        testVal= msg.sender;
    } 

   function getMSGSender() public view returns ( address) {
     return testVal;
   }
}

contract Test1 is Test2 {

}
```

You can call `Test1.getMSGSender()` and get the expected result.

You didn't mention what you're using to test the contract. Here it is in Remix to show it working without worrying about client-side concerns.

[image]

As an aside, you could `address public testVal;` and that would give you a "free" getter (`function testVal() public view returns(address)...`) that does *exactly* what your function does. I left it as is to help focus on one issue at a time.

A more succinct version:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Test2 
{
    address public testVal;

    constructor() public {
        testVal= msg.sender;
    } 

}

contract Test1 is Test2 {}
```

Hope it helps.